# gradle UTF-8 issue with Android-Studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio, encoding, utf-8

I have an encoding issue using gradle through Android-Studio 1.5

In a project, I created a gradle task to copy a java template file and replacing tags using values found in a properties file.
The properties file contains unicode and UTF_8 strings.

When I execute the gradle from the command line, the generated java file is corect and contain the UTF-8 strings.

When I execute the gradle task from Android-Studio, the generated java file is wrong ans contains ? characters for each string.

Example:

## Configure.java:

```
public class Configure {
    public String LANGUAGE1 = "@LANGUAGE1@";
    public String LANGUAGE2 = "@LANGUAGE2@";
}
```

## language.properties:

```
language1=\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a\u0629
language2=العربية
```

## build.gradle:

```
task configure (type: Copy) {

    // Read Properties
    Properties props = new Properties()
    def propFile = new File("language.properties")
    props.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(propFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    // Create token replacement HashMap
    def tokens = [:]
    props.each {
        k,v -> tokens.put(k.toUpperCase(),props.get(k));
    }

    // Copy file template and replace tokens
    from '../Template/Configure.java'
    into '../Generated'
    filter(
        ReplaceTokens, tokens: tokens
    )
}
```

This the generated java file using the command line

## Correct generated Configure.java:

```
public class Configure {
    public String LANGUAGE1 = "العربية";
    public String LANGUAGE2 = "العربية";
}
```

This is generated java file using the Android-Studio

## Wrong generated Configure.java:

```
public class Configure {
    public String LANGUAGE1 = "???????";
    public String LANGUAGE2 = "???????";
}
```

In Android Studio, File Encodings in File/Settings... is configured with UTF-8 for:

- IDE Encoding
- Project Encoding
- Default encoding for properties files

I'm working on this problem since a couple of days and I have no more ideas.

Can you help me ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

check this , on bottom right of your screen (select the one that works for you).
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Unfortunately, I'm already in the UTF-8 Encoding. And because I set UTF-8 for .properties files in settings, the encoding box is set and locked to "UTF-8".

The generated file is not just badly displayed by Android-Studio, it is really badly generated, as I can see using an hexa editor.

Regards

Comment: You can easily check from your side: add the following line in a task: "println 'العربية' and check the Android-Studio output. In my case, I have ???????

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem yesterday.
I open File/Settings... and select Build, Execution, Deployment/Compiler in the left pane.

Then, you can enter Command-line Options for Gradle-based Android projects.

I add the following option:
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

[File/Settings...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ugz9.png)
You can also set GRADLE_OPTS with the same value as an environment variable.

Regards